# I am having trouble understanding IBM procedures

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I am reading this file "readme_5202_P8CPE_IF001.htm" ([Content Platform Engine 5.2.0.2 Interim Fix 1](http://delivery04.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/IMA/0401j/2/readme_5202_P8CPE_IF001.htm)), and I encountered this procedure:

> Copy the new Engine-xx.ear file into the following directory. This directory is a staging location. Do not delete or overwrite the currently deployed Engine-xx.ear file.
>
> **Windows**
>   installation_location\ContentEngine\lib
>
> **UNIX**
>   installation_location/ContentEngine/lib

What I don't understand is, how am I supposed to copy the Engine-xx.ear file to the specified directory without deleting or overwriting the existing Engine-xx.ear file there? Please bear with me if my understanding in English is not good.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a note (poorly explained, though) **not** to overwrite the original file (*Engine-xx.ear*), but to rename it, *as e.g. Engine-xx-orig.ear*, and store it aside (to have it if something goes bad with your upgrade) before copying/building the version from a fix pack to that same location.

Which is called a staging environment.

Because it's used to build a *WAR/EAR* for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the rest of the document, I belive that they are trying to tell you that you should follow their instructions carefully, and not try to be clever and overwrite the deployed application (at some other location).

I would give it a shot and overwrite whatever is in `installation_location\ContentEngine\lib`, the staging location. Make a backup of the files you overwrite in case it doesn't work out.